# Unexpected results from Position

Tags: list-manipulation

I am obtaining a very unexpected result and I would really like to not get this result:

```
vector = {1, 1, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1/4, 1/4, 1/96 (11 + Sqrt[97]), 1/6, 1/6,
    1/8, 1/8, 1/10, 1/12, 1/12, 1/20, 1/20, 1/36, 1/36, 1/36, 1/36, 1/36,
    1/40, 1/80, 1/80, 1/96 (11 - Sqrt[97]), 1/96, 1/144, 1/144, 1/576, 1/576};

Position[vector, 1/2]

(*  Out[1224]= {{4}, {5}, {8, 2, 2, 2}, {26, 2, 2, 2, 2}}  *)
```

I am expecting the result to be `{{4}, {5}}`, I am very unsure where these extra values are coming from!

Comment: Use `Position[vector, 1/2, 1]` and to learn why take a look at `FullForm` of both `vector` and `1/2`.

Comment: @Kuba amazing thank you!

Comment: Please note the tag [tag:bugs] has [a very specific usage](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info) on this site.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry was unaware. I will know for next time.

Comment: That's ok.  Too many arcane practices for everyone to keep up with. :)

Comment: The extra `1/2`s comes from the fact that `Sqrt` is equivalently a `1/2`-th power. Use `FullForm[vector]` to show the internal form used actually by the kernels.

Comment: [The displayed form may substantially differ from the internal form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219/5478)